# Session timeout redirection in Devexpress GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I am using ASP.Net MVC.
I have placed [Authorize] attribute on all controllers to be able to redirect to login page when authentication fails. But on grid callbacks it does not replace the html content with login page content but rather it shows a message with the login page html content.

The scenario is explained in detail below:

- Session times out
- User clicks on a grid to sort / paginate
- Grid goes for a callback
- Due to [Authorize] attribute specified, the authentication fails and it redirects to the action for login
- The action for login returns the login partial view
- Instead of replacing the html content, the html response is displayed as a message in message box

How can I solve this problem to be able to show login screen when session time out.

It occurs only on local machine.

Comment: you have to write custom attriute and handle for ajax case as well:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/aspnet-mvc-check-user-is-logged-in-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue. I have done the following to solve the issue.
I have added the following in grid view to invoke a java script method when callback error occurs

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.CallbackError = "callbackErrorHandler";
```

and added this java script method.

```
function callbackErrorHandler(s, e) {
    if (e.message != '') {
        e.handled = true;
        e.cancel = true;
        var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")';
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```